# Reader.ReadToEnd();

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, streamreader

bat file which runs a .exe which then writes to console, however, the result returns all at once after the executable has finished and not during the execution.

I've run the .bat manually from my desktop which works fine and returns the result line by line, however no luck line by line in my C# app. any ideas?

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Desktop\TEST\test.bat"; /
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Desktop\TEST\";
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

using (Process Process = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
  using (var reader = (Process.StandardOutput))
  {
  Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
  }
}
```

Comment: have you checked if it is an issue with the file permission?

Comment: Are you doing this from a win forms application? if so, as standard this code is probably running on the UI thread. this will mean its probably blocked till the end of the batch. process this in another thread, and then pass the resulting stream back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) should explain the behaviour you are seeing, ReadToEnd is a synchronous operation, BeginOutputReadLine is asychronous so should suit your needs better.